# Do different instances of DataContext share the same Connection?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here's a code snippet:

```
private static ApplicationParameter TryGet(MyDataContext ctxt, string parameterName) {
  return ctxt.GetTable<ApplicationParameter>().Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == parameterName.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
}

private static Dictionary<string, string> _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static string GetValue(string parameterName) {
  if (!_cache.ContainsKey(parameterName))
    using (var ctxt = new MyDataContext()) {
      var ap = TryGet(ctxt, parameterName);
      if (ap != null)
        _cache[parameterName] = ap.Value;
      else
        _cache[parameterName] = null;
    }
    return _cache[parameterName];
}
```

This code works fine most of the time.  Under load testing, however, we sometimes get the infamous "Open DataReader" error in the `TryGet()` method, with the call stack showing it came through `GetValue()`.

For the life of me, I cannot see how this is possible.  I am clearly using a `using` block around the call to `TryGet`, with a new instance of `MyDataContext`, and there's only one query.  So how can there possibly be an open `DataReader` already there?

Unless... there's some shared connection between all instances of `MyDataContext` (which obviously inherits from `DataContext`), and when two threads try simultaneously to use the `Connection` property, even of two different data contexts, somehow they're both accessing the same `DataReader`?

Could this be true?  What other explanation could there be?

**EDIT:** I put a logger in the `OnCreated` method of `MyDataContext` and logged the value of `GetHashCode` for both the data context and its `Connection` property.  No duplicates there, so I guess they're not sharing the same object - at least, not in normal usage.  Haven't seen the "open datareader" error since installing the logging.  But even if they're not using the same connection object, maybe somehow they're still sharing the same connection to the DB?